# How to access to type using function argument

Tags: typescript

I have been trying to get the specific type based on an function argument but I can't find any way in typescript.

This "step" argument is actually a key in the slice

```
type Slice1 = {
    info: string
}

type Slice2 = {
    info: string
}

type MyAppState = {
    step1: Slice1;
    step2: Slice2;
}

function useStep<T>(step: keyof T): T[typeof step] {
  const [state] = useContext(ExternalContext);
  return state[step];
}

const step1 = useStep<MyAppState>('step1'); <-- **should return Slice1 type**
```

I want to get the correct type depending on the key.

Comment: would it make sense to pass anything other than `MyAppState` to the `useStep` function? The solution is probably to use `<T extends keyof MyAppState>(step: T): MyAppState[T]` but I'm not sure what your goal is.

Comment: The important thing is that the key itself needs to be generic, rather than just `keyof T`, so that your return type can be based on this specific key.  In the unlikely case that `ExternalContext` can have multiple types of state, you can make both the state and the key generic like so `function useStep<T, K extends keyof T>(step: K): T[K]`, but you would no longer be able to specify T without also specifying K, so you couldn't type `useStep<MyAppState>('step1')`.  If the only possible type of state is `MyAppState` then only the key needs to be generic and it will be what the others have said.

Comment: My goal is to keep MyAppState outside useStep hook definition because I want this state to be specified by the consumer. The ideal scenario might be: const mySlice = useStep<AnyState>('keyInAnyState') --> only the slice type

Answer (score 1):

Is the fact that we hardcode `MyAppState` okay with you?:

```js
function useStep<TKey extends keyof MyAppState>(step: TKey): MyAppState[TKey] {
  const [state] = useContext(ExternalContext);
  return state[step];
}

const step1 = useStep('step1'); // <-- returns Slice1 type
```

EDIT:
Since you don't want to hardcode `MyAppState` in your type, you can use a [curried function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying):

```js
function useStep<T>() {
  return <TKey extends keyof T>(step: TKey): T[TKey] => {
    const [state] = useContext(ExternalContext);
    return state[step];
  }
}

const step1 = useStep<MyAppState>()('step1'); // <-- returns Slice1 type
```

Comment: My goal is to keep MyAppState outside useStep hook definition because I want this to be specified by the consumer. The ideal scenario might be: const mySlice = useStep<AnyState>('keyInAnyState') --> only the slice type

Comment: Wow nice approach, thank you. I came out with this solution inspired by redux: selectors 

`
function useStep<TState = {}, TSelected = unknown>( selector: (state: TState) => TSelected):TSelected {
  const [state] = useContext(ExternalContext);
  return state[step];
}
`
`
const step1 = useStep((state: MyAppState) => state.step1);
`

Comment: @AlexisPatiño The issue with your solution is that it doesn't check whether the key of the interface is used: `useStep((state: MyAppState) => 12);` is valid and it returns `number`.